# Node Steam protobuf

Tags: node.js, steam

I'm quite new with node stuff and I tried to figure out why I'm getting 
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNdEA.png)

That error happens in the very first line where I'm requiring steam-module: "var steam = require('steam')".
Obviously GET-request is targeting to wrong place, should be at least 'http://localhost:8080/protobufs/...' to get the resource correctly. Maybe something is wrong in my webpack config or package.json?

Is there any very comprehensive examples how to get started with node-steam? I'm using latest node (v7.7.0) and npm (v4.1.2).

EDIT: Here are package.json

```
{
  "name": "steam-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "js/login.js",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "babel": "babel",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "steam": "^1.4.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

and webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/js/login.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [/js/],
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    },
    watch: true
};
```

Comment: check package.json, if steam is inside. also check node_modules, if it is installed.

Comment: yeah they are inside and installed.